# transfer data from components in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, frontend

I have 2 components. In one component I render map of table rows =>

this is place, where tDs.map is rendered

```
    this.state.dataOld.map(it =>(
<>
<tr onClick={()=>{it.selected_=!it.selected_;this.forceUpdate()}} value={it} key={it.id}>
{this.tDs.map(fnc => fnc(it,this.hide,this))}
</tr>
</>))
```

dataOld is array of 2 objects

tDs is array like

```
function(it,hide,a){return !hide.id ? <td>{it.id}</td> : null},
function(it,hide,a){return !hide.category3 ? <td>{it.category3}</td> : null},
function(it,hide,a){return !hide.edit ? <td>
    <Button onClick={() => a.setState({edit:!a.state.edit,element:it})}>    
    </Button>
</td> : null}
```

the thing i interested in is `a.setState({edit:!a.state.edit,element:it})}`

I render another component inside of first

```
<Edit isOpen={this.state.edit} editBack={this.editBack} th={this} element={this.state.element}/>
```

I transfer my `this.state.element` to Edit, inside Edit component I'm doing something like this:

```
elem = {};
componentDidUpdate(){
        this.elem = this.props.element
        console.log(this.elem)
    }
...
<Input onChange={ e => {this.elem.packagingType = e.target.value; console.log(e.target.value)} } ... />
```

so, the problem is: I transfer `this.state.element` to Edit component, then in Edit component I make new variable `elem` and make it be equal to `this.props.elem` I transferred

**the problem starting here, the first, (original, natural) `this.state.element` is changing, but I dont change dataOld, I dont change any element that has been rendered, I really dont undestand, how it works here.**

My guess was about this place

```
<Edit isOpen={this.state.edit} editBack={this.editBack} th={this} element={this.state.element}/>
```

I think that when I'm doing `element={this.state.element}` I somehow connect this 2 things and when I change `element` inside of `Edit`, the natural `this.state.element` is changing too.

Codesandbox example:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/7wk8689op6?fontsize=14

when you press a button near every row, then change data and press cancel, the original data is changing, I dont understand why

Comment: Hi Ivan, could you perhaps start your question with the actual question you have and then provide some detail? It's hard to ascertain what you're doing, what your problem is, or where we might be able to assist.

Comment: @coreyward I make some changes

Comment: Could you provide [minimum viable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so SO community could help you solve this problem? Even after edits I couldnt get a grip on the essence of the problem, provided MCVE would help greatly. Thanks!

Comment: @AndyTheos added an example and description, thank you.

Comment: Example is there, but i still don't understand what exactly are you trying to achieve. If, IMO, you were trying to do a simple CRUD table, where you can open an editable  Form for each distinct field, then your state and app structure is way off and complicated. You can check [this React doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to get a better understanding of architecture, example in this doc are somewhat similar to yours, i guess.

Comment: @AndyTheos It is a table with some rows I get from server. I am trying to edit a row. so I transfer it to other component, then I edit it in there. BUT! I dont need to transfer it back because it happens automatically, that is a magic I dont understand, why is it happening, the question is not about `how to do it` (cause I made it, obviously), it is about `how it happens there`, I just dont understand

Comment: @AndyTheos see, I forwarded `it` from `dataOld` to `tDs` when made a map, then, inside `tDs` I forwarded it to `this.state.element`, then I forwarded `this.state.element` to `<Edit />` and all these forwards made a magical (in my opinion) connection, so when I changed `element` inside of `<Edit />`, it changed original `it` inside of `dataOld`

Comment: @IvanBurilichev Part of the issue here is that you're using terminology that has no meaning in the problem context. You say you “transfer”  a property of `state` to another component (`Edit`), then you start talking about how you haven't changed a totally different variable (`dataOld`); later you talk about “connecting things”, and that you don't understand. Meanwhile I have no idea what your problem is still, but I suspect you just don't yet grok state in React.

Comment: @coreyward but when you press cancel button, the original object in array, that you edited is changing, that can you explain work of this stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understood the question.
When I put an object to the `Edit` component, and then change an object inside of component, the original object is changing too because I didn't make a new version of this object, but I gave to `Edit` a link to this object.